# Injecting component at runtime

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to build a modular React that displays widgets. For example, You might have a calendar widget and a clock widget.

Each widget being a different project, I am looking for a way to inject them at runtime in my main react app, knowing that they were not transpiled with it.

I looked into React.createElement(), but I did not managed to get it to work

- Each Widget in of it self is a react project
- Want to compile them seperately and then import them in my main react app while it is running.

You can find the source code here https://github.com/fastboyz/dashy-react

Comment: I've done this in the past with web-components; should definitely be possible with react components as well.

Comment: Do you have some documentation? I am having a hard time finding any

Comment: Is there a reason you need it to compile separately? You will need to deal with a lot more issues, especially security.

Comment: Partly it a poof of concept, but I ultimately want to build something like Magic Mirror, but with some sort of a market with a user interface and all to make it easier for  casual users

Comment: If you have any documentation on the subject it would be greatly appreciated.